# Ошибка с наследованием в CSS

Tags: css, наследование

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Commersion</title>
    <style>
        .firststroke{color:blue};
        #ccc {color:gold};
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <p class="firststroke">первая строка</p>
            <p id="ccc">вторая строка</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему селектор id начинает работать только если удалить селектор class.

Comment: Уберите `;`....

Comment: Спасибо большое